# Suppress C warning messages in R

Tags: c, r, gcc, libsvm

I am calling an R function from the R package e1071 which is interfaced with libsvm (a C program). This function is passing C (printf) warning messages to the R console. I know this because the warning messages are of the form (warning:...) whereas R warning messages are capitalized (i.e. Warning:...).

I've tried everything to get rid of these messages in R (sink, suppressWarnings, invisible) but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why so vague?  Are you interfacing to libsvm via an R package?  Or are you working on something custom?  GCC is a compiler, I doubt run-time warnings are coming from it, more likely they are printfs in the libsvm C code.

Comment: yep e1071 package - I think you're right, the messages are coming from a printf statement. Do I need to go into the C code and delete it? or is there something I can do from R?

Comment: also I don't remember ever installing libsvm on my machine, I just downloaded the R package. Does that mean the libsvm source code is in the R package?

Comment: I think this is related to [your recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842024/suppressing-warning-messages-in-e1071-in-r), and [your other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842301/suppressing-warning-messages-in-e1071-in-r). Try and keep them all in the same place.

Comment: In case it helps, the code printing the messages is in the file `src/svm.cpp` in the `e1071` package sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function uses *stdio* instead of `Rprintf`/`REprintf` or `warning` which is why re-direction of the R output won't work. The proper solution is to fix the calls in `libsvm` to use R output instead.

Hacking the *stdio* output is possible - you can re-direct the output to your own pipe and do what you want with it, but a) it's a bit of work in C and b) it's dangerous because you need to restore the standard behavior after you're done with the function - even if it errors out and c) in may interact with R output if used on a shell.

If you want a really whacky, dirty yet quick solution, run your function in `collect(parallel(..., silent=TRUE))[[1]]` from `multicore` - it suppresses *stdout* (you can add `multicore:::closeStderr()` if you want to suppress *stderr* as well).