# suppress output of a C function

Tags: r

I'm using a function out of some library that calls a C function which prints a lot of stuff out to standard out that I don't need.

I've tried using `sink` (tried both "messages" and "output" for `type`), `capture.output`, `suppressWarnings`, `suppressMessages` to try to suppress that output - all to no effect, it still prints the stuff out. What else can I use? And why exactly does the above not work?

I don't have access to the source of the function to check how it's printing stuff, and the library is private, so no reproducible examples unfortunately.

I'll also love any workarounds for the above problem, no matter how ugly.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Simon Urbanek suggests a few workarounds [in his answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842573/suppress-c-warning-messages-in-r/8842855#8842855).  If his `collect(parallel())` hack works for you, then we can close this question as a duplicate.