# Suppress messages from underlying C-function in R

Tags: c, r, console, printf, output

In a script I often call the function `Rcplex()`, which prints "CPLEX environment opened" and "Closed CPLEX environment" to the console. Since the function is called rather frequently, it prints this very often, which is quite annoying. Is there a way to suppress this? I tried `sink()`, `suppressWarnings/Messages` or `invisible(catch.output())` but none of these did the trick. I proceeded to check the code of `Rcplex()` and found where the printing to the console happens. `Rcplex()` calls an underlying C-function (`Rcplex.c`). In the [code of rcplex.c](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/Rcplex.c?view=markup&revision=2&root=rcplex) I located the commands which cause the printing:

```
    REprintf("CPLEX environment opened\n");
    REprintf("Closed CPLEX environment\n");
```

Is there a way to capture the output from `REprintf()` so that it does not get printed to the R-console? One way would obviously be to mess around with the `Rcplex.c` file and delete the corresponding lines. However, this would not be a very clean solution, which is why I'm asking for another way to capture the output from C-functions.

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842573/suppress-c-warning-messages-in-r already?

Comment: Yes but the answer to the problem in the link you posted specifically states that the underlying function uses `stdio` instead of `REprintf`. Here, however, `REprintf` is used. That's why I was hoping for a 'cleaner' solution than the one in the answer in the link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You had problems using `sink()` and `capture.output()` normally because `sink()` does not redirect output from `REprintf`, as we see in comments from the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fed0444824567e1c4edff234fc5c2fb1c99bbc84/src/main/printutils.c) for `REprintf`:

```
/* =========
 * Printing:
 * =========
 *
 * All printing in R is done via the functions Rprintf and REprintf
 * or their (v) versions Rvprintf and REvprintf.
 * These routines work exactly like (v)printf(3).  Rprintf writes to
 * ``standard output''.  It is redirected by the sink() function,
 * and is suitable for ordinary output.  REprintf writes to
 * ``standard error'' and is useful for error messages and warnings.
 * It is not redirected by sink().
```

However, we can use `type = "message"` to deal with this; from `help("capture.output")`:

> Messages sent to stderr() (including those from message, warning and
>   stop) are captured by type = "message". Note that this can be "unsafe" and should only be used with care.

First I make a C++ function with the same behavior you're dealing with:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector example_function(NumericVector x) {
    REprintf("CPLEX environment opened\n");
    REprintf("Closed CPLEX environment\n");
    // As mentioned by Dirk Eddelbuettel in the comments,
    // Rcpp::Rcerr goes into the same REprintf() stream:
    Rcerr << "Some more stuff\n";
    return x;
}
```

If I call it from R normally, I get:

```
example_function(42)

CPLEX environment opened
Closed CPLEX environment
Some more stuff
[1] 42
```

However, I could instead do this:

```
invisible(capture.output(example_function(42), type = "message"))

[1] 42
```

And while the output is is printed to the console, the message is not.

#### Warning

I would be remiss if I didn't mention the warning from the help file I quoted above:

> Note that this can be "unsafe" and should only be used with care.

The reason is that this will eliminate all output from actual errors as well. Consider the following:

```
> log("A")
Error in log("A") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> invisible(capture.output(log("A"), type = "message"))
>
```

You may or may not want to therefore send the captured output to a text file in case you have to diagnose something that went wrong. For example:

```
invisible(capture.output(log("A"), type = "message", file = "example.txt"))
```

Then I don't have to see the message in the console, but if I need to check `example.txt` afterward, the message is there:

```
Error in log("A") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Comment: You could even show `Rcpp::Rcerr << "Some more stuff\n";` as that goes into the same `REprintf()` stream.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Done!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. This indeed helped me fix the issue!

Comment: I can't award the bounty yet. SO tells me I can award it in 7 hours only which I will gladly do! :)

Comment: @YukiJ Glad this helped!