# Suppress error message when using fitdist() from the fitdistrplus package

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, error-suppression, fitdistrplus

I am using certain functions from the `fitdistrplus` package as a part of a package I am creating.

I am attempting to prevent any error messages from displaying in the console when the functions are run and instead want to record the error messages in an error log that I am creating.

In most cases, using `tryCatch()` has allowed me to achieve this.

But specifically for the `fitdist()` function, I cannot suppress the error message being printed in the console even though the message is being written to the error log (meaning the `tryCatch()` expression is functioning).

I have replicated my issue in the code below.

```
library(fitdistrplus)

file.create("error_log.txt")

func_desc<-function(x){
  tryCatch({
    descdist(data = x)
  },error = function(e){
    write(x = paste(Sys.time(),"Error in func_desc :",e$message,sep = " "),file = "error_log.txt",append = T,sep = "\n")
  })
}

func_fit<-function(x,dist){
  tryCatch({
    fitdist(data = x,distr = dist)
  },error = function(e){
    write(x = paste(Sys.time(),"Error in func_fit :",e$message,sep = " "),file = "error_log.txt",append = T,sep = "\n")
  })
}

# Creating a vector of repeated values which will result in an error
test<-rep(x = 1,times = 10)

func_desc(x = test)
# Results in an error and the message is written to the error log and not printed in the console

func_fit(x = test,dist = "beta")
# Results in an error and the message is both written to the error log and printed in the console
```

I want to suppress this error message being printed by `func_fit()`.

**I have already tried the following alternatives:**

1. `try()` with `silent = TRUE`. The error message still gets printed.
2. `conditionMessage()` gives the same result.
3. `withCallingHandlers()` has been suggested in some posts and threads but I am unsure of how to implement it correctly.
4. Using `invisible()` with the functions still prints the error.

Comment: hey, i think the problem is, your error message comes from C code. The optim calls the C_optim file in source `.External2(C_optim, par, fn1, gr1, method, con, lower, 
        upper)` calls the C_optim function. Since i'm not exactly sure if the error has this origin, i'm not writing this as answer. This would explain why you can't mute it. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842573/suppress-c-warning-messages-in-r) ) So either this works for you or another approach is (not recommended) rewriting the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using the solution suggested in that thread but the `multicore` package is no longer available on CRAN. The `multicore` page says `parallel` can be used as an alternative. I have gone through its documentation but I can't figure out how I can use it in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes about because `fitdist` (or actually, `mledist` which is called by `fitdist`) is already doing some error catching.  The original error is in `optim` and has been caught, and then `mledist` *prints* to the console the error message.  So what you're seeing isn't really an error or even a warning, it's a print statement with the content of a caught error message.

The bit of `mledist` that does this is:

```
    if (inherits(opttryerror, "try-error")) {
        warnings("The function optim encountered an error and stopped.")
        if (getOption("show.error.messages")) 
            print(attr(opttryerror, "condition"))
        return(list(estimate = rep(NA, length(vstart)), convergence = 100, 
            loglik = NA, hessian = NA, optim.function = opt.fun, 
            fix.arg = fix.arg, optim.method = meth, fix.arg.fun = fix.arg.fun, 
            counts = c(NA, NA)))
    }
```

This isn't really good practice, precisely because it causes the problem you now have; it stops other people handling errors systematically.

As you can see from that code, you could switch this off by setting the `show.error.messages` option to FALSE:

```
options(show.error.messages = FALSE)
```

but you want to be careful about that as you won't see any error messages for the rest of the R session.  You definitely don't want to do it to someone else's session.

Another alternative is to use `sink("extra-error-messages.txt")` to send all the printing to the console somewhere (maybe even to your `error_log.txt` but I'm not sure if that would cause problems with multiple things writing to it).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gives me a good idea of what was generating that error message. I don't want to disable error messages printing completely since the functions are part of a package I am developing and that might cause issues for anyone installing the package. I will try out using sink and see if that works.

Comment: Using sink works just fine. Since I was iterating this function over multiple variables, I initially got an error saying "sink stack is full" but I could work around that. I have tried out way too many methods to resolve this issue for over weeks now. You can't imagine my relief at this moment to not see that ugly thing printing on the console anymore. Really appreciate the help :)